# How to pass data (and references) between scenes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I pass score value from one scene to another?

I've tried the following:

**Scene one:**

```
void Start () {
    score = 0;
    updateScoreView ();
    StartCoroutine (DelayLoadlevel(20));
}

public void updateScoreView(){
    score_text.text = "The Score: "+ score;
}

public void AddNewScore(int NewscoreValue){
    score = score + NewscoreValue;
    updateScoreView ();
}

IEnumerator DelayLoadlevel(float seconds){        
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
    secondsLeft = seconds;
    loadingStart = true;
    do {        
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    } while(--secondsLeft >0);

    // here I should store my last score before move to level two
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("player_score", score);
    Application.LoadLevel (2);
}
```

**Scene two:**

```
public Text score_text;
private int old_score;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {    
    old_score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("player_score");
    score_text.text = "new score" + old_score.ToString ();      
}
```

but nothing displayed on screen, and there's no error.

Is this the correct way to pass data ?

I am using Unity 5 free edition, develop game for Gear VR (meaning the game will run in android devices).

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's exactly the problem? Is it that the second scene is not loaded? Or is it that the displayed score is incorrect?

Comment: not next scene loaded but without my score , is this correct way to store data ? is it like sharedPreference in android

Comment: What is the value of `old_score` ? You can see it by adding `Debug.Log(old_score);` in your `Start()` method.

Comment: oh I am stupid I don't attach text canvas to my script to display score

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Besides playerPrefs another dirty way is to  preserve an object during level loading by calling DontDestroyOnLoad on it.

```
DontDestroyOnLoad (transform.gameObject);
```

Any script attached to the game object will survive and so will the variables in the script.
The DontDestroyOnLoad function is generally used to preserve an entire GameObject, including the components attached to it, and any child objects it has in the hierarchy.

You could create an empty GameObject, and place only the script containing the variables you want preserved on it.

Comment: There is another nice one - "info object" http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/532656/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-data-between-scenes.html

Answer (score 187):

There are many ways to do this but the solution to this depends on the type of data you want to pass between scenes. Components/Scripts and GameObjects are destroyed when new scene is loaded and even when marked as `static`.

In this answer you can find

- 1. Use the `static` keyword
- 2. Use `DontDestroyOnLoad`
- 3. Store the data local

  - 3a `PlayerPrefs`
  - 3b serialize to XML/JSON/Binary and use `FileIO`

---

**1. Use the `static` keyword.**

Use this method if the variable to pass to the next scene is not a component, does **not** inherit from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) and is not a GameObject then make the variable to be `static`.

Built-in primitive data types such as `int`, `bool`, `string`, `float`, `double`. All those variables can be made a `static` variable.

**Example of built-in primitive data types that *can* be marked as static**:

```
static int counter = 0;
static bool enableAudio = 0;
static float timer = 100;
```

These should work without problems.

---

**Example of Objects that *can* be marked as static**:

```
public class MyTestScriptNoMonoBehaviour
{

}
```

then

```
static MyTestScriptNoMonoBehaviour testScriptNoMono;

void Start()
{
    testScriptNoMono = new MyTestScriptNoMonoBehaviour();
}
```

Notice that the class does not inherit from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html). This should work.

---

**Example of Objects that *cannot* be marked as static**:

Anything that inherits from [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html), [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) or [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) will **not** work.

**1A**.Anything that inherits from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)

```
public class MyTestScript : MonoBehaviour 
{

}
```

then

```
static MyTestScript testScript;

void Start()
{
    testScript = gameObject.AddComponent<MyTestScript>();
}
```

This will **not** work because it inherits from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).

**1B**.All [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html):

```
static GameObject obj;

void Start()
{
    obj = new GameObject("My Object");
}
```

This will **not** work either because it is a [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) and [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) inherit from an [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html).

**Unity will always destroy its [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) even if they are declared with the `static` keyword.**

See **#2** for a workaround.

---

**2.Use the [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) function**.

You only need to use this if the data to keep or pass to the next scene inherits from [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html), [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) or is a [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html). This solves the problem described in **1A** and **1B**.

You can use it to make this GameObject not to destroy when scene unloads:

```
void Awake() 
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
}
```

---

You can even use it with the `static` keyword solve problem from **1A** and **1B**:

```
public class MyTestScript : MonoBehaviour 
{

}
```

then

```
static MyTestScript testScript;

void Awake() 
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
}

void Start()
{
    testScript = gameObject.AddComponent<MyTestScript>();
}
```

The `testScript` variable will now be preserved when new scene loads.

**3.Save to local storage then load during next scene.**

This method should be used when this is a game data that must be preserved when the game is closed and reopened. Example of this is the player high-score, the game settings such as music volume, objects locations, joystick profile data and so on.

Thare are two ways to save this:

**3A**.Use the [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) API.

Use if you have just few variables to save. Let's say player score:

```
int playerScore = 80;
```

And we want to save playerScore:

Save the score in the `OnDisable` function

```
void OnDisable()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", playerScore);
}
```

Load it in the `OnEnable` function

```
void OnEnable()
{
    playerScore  =  PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score");
}
```

**3B**.Serialize the data to json, xml or binaray form then save using one of the C# file API such as [`File.WriteAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) to save and load files.

Use this method if there are many variables to save.

General, you need to create a class that does not inherit from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html). This class you should use to hold your game data so that in can be easily serialized or de-serialized.

Example of data to save:

```
[Serializable]
public class PlayerInfo
{
    public List<int> ID = new List<int>();
    public List<int> Amounts = new List<int>();
    public int life = 0;
    public float highScore = 0;
}
```

Grab the `DataSaver` class which is a wrapper over [`File.WriteAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) that makes saving data easier from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40966346/3785314) post.

*Create new instance:*

```
PlayerInfo saveData = new PlayerInfo();
saveData.life = 99;
saveData.highScore = 40;
```

*Save data from PlayerInfo to a file named "players":*

```
DataSaver.saveData(saveData, "players");
```

*Load data from a file named "players":*

```
PlayerInfo loadedData = DataSaver.loadData<PlayerInfo>("players");
```

Comment: This is a more comprehensive answer than the accepted one. Thanks!

Comment: hi @Programmer, is this #3B method possible use in WebGL games?

Comment: There is a 4th way I often use. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60408573/7111561)

Comment: @Programmer "Components/Scripts [...] are destroyed when new scene is loaded [...] *even when marked as static*." (Emphasis mine) I just tried this with a static script/class and it stays alive across scenes. If I change one of its attributes in one scene, then load another scene, the data remains changed. Maybe by "Components/Scripts" you only meant scripts that are attached to game objects?

Answer (score 59):

There is another way:

### [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html)

`ScriptableObject`s are basically data containers but may also implement own logic. They "live" only in the `Assets` like prefabs. They can **not** be used to store data **permanently**, but they store the data during **one session** so they can be used to share **data and references** between Scenes ... and - something I also often needed - between Scenes and an `AnimatorController`!

#### Script

First you need a script similar to `MonoBehaviour`s. A simple example of a `ScriptableObject` might look like

```
// fileName is the default name when creating a new Instance
// menuName is where to find it in the context menu of Create
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Data", menuName = "Examples/ExampleScriptableObject")]
public class ExampleScriptableObject : ScriptableObject
{
    public string someStringValue = "";
    public CustomDataClass someCustomData = null;
    public Transform someTransformReference = null;

    // Could also implement some methods to set/read data,
    // do stuff with the data like parsing between types, fileIO etc

    // Especially ScriptableObjects also implement OnEnable and Awake
    // so you could still fill them with permanent data via FileIO at the beginning of your app and store the data via FileIO in OnDestroy !!
}

// If you want the data to be stored permanently in the editor
// and e.g. set it via the Inspector
// your types need to be Serializable!
//
// I intentionally used a non-serializable class here to show that also 
// non Serializable types can be passed between scenes 
public class CustomDataClass
{
    public int example;
    public Vector3 custom;
    public Dictionary<int, byte[]> data;
}
```

#### Create Instances

You can create instances of `ScriptableObject` either via script

```
var scriptableObject = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<ExampleScriptableObject>();
```

or to make things easier use the [`[CreateAssetMenu]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CreateAssetMenuAttribute.html) as shown in the example above.

As this created `ScriptabeObject` instance lives in the `Assets` it is not bound to a scene and can therefore be referenced everywhere!

This when you want to share the data between two Scenes or also e.g. the Scene and an `AnimatorController` all you need to do is reference this `ScriptableObject` instance in both.

#### Fill Data

I often use e.g. one component to fill the data like

```
public class ExampleWriter : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here you drag in the ScriptableObject instance via the Inspector in Unity
    [SerializeField] private ExampleScriptableObject example;

    public void StoreData(string someString, int someInt, Vector3 someVector, List<byte[]> someDatas)
    {
        example.someStringValue = someString;
        example.someCustomData = new CustomDataClass
                                 {
                                     example = someInt;
                                     custom = someVector;
                                     data = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
                                 };
        for(var i = 0; i < someDatas.Count; i++)
        {
            example.someCustomData.data.Add(i, someDatas[i]);
        }
        example.someTransformReference = transform;
    }
}
```

called e.g. in `Awake` or at any time to even have runtime updated values.

#### Consume Data

So after you have written and stored your required data into this `ExampleScriptableObject` instance every other class in any Scene or `AnimatorController` or also other `ScriptableObject`s can read this data on just the same way:

```
public class ExampleConsumer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here you drag in the same ScriptableObject instance via the Inspector in Unity
    [SerializeField] private ExampleScriptableObject example;

    public void ExampleLog()
    {
        Debug.Log($"string: {example.someString}", this);
        Debug.Log($"int: {example.someCustomData.example}", this);
        Debug.Log($"vector: {example.someCustomData.custom}", this);
        Debug.Log($"data: There are {example.someCustomData.data.Count} entries in data.", this);

        Debug.Log($"The data writer {example.someTransformReference.name} is at position {example.someTransformReference.position}", this);
    }
}
```

---

#### Persistence

As said the changes in a `ScriptableObject` itself are only in the Unity Editor really persistent.

In a build they are only persistent during the same session.

Therefore if needed I often combine the session persistence with some FileIO (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44542726/7111561)'s section 3b) for loading and deserializing the values once at session begin (or whenever needed) from the hard drive and serialize and store them to a file once on session end (`OnApplicationQuit`) or whenever needed.

(This won't work with references of course.)

Comment: Good solution without any additionals. This code also is better suited for unit-testing. Thank you for this detailed answer.

Comment: Great answer! I prefer this approach also. I would just like to add that, if the scene that does not contain reference to particular SO is loaded during session, SO will be removed from memory and it's current state will be lost. In order to avoid this one could set hideFlags = HideFlags.DontUnloadUnusedAsset in, let say, OnEnable().

Comment: I think this answer needs more upvotes in 2021.

Answer (score 5):

I use a functional approach I call Stateless Scenes.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class MySceneBehaviour: MonoBehaviour {
    private static MySceneParams loadSceneRegister = null;

    public MySceneParams sceneParams;

    public static void loadMyScene(MySceneParams sceneParams, System.Action<MySceneOutcome> callback) {
        MySceneBehaviour.loadSceneRegister = sceneParams;
        sceneParams.callback = callback;
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("MyScene");
    }

    public void Awake() {
        if (loadSceneRegister != null) sceneParams = loadSceneRegister;
        loadSceneRegister = null; // the register has served its purpose, clear the state
    }

    public void endScene (MySceneOutcome outcome) {
        if (sceneParams.callback != null) sceneParams.callback(outcome);
        sceneParams.callback = null; // Protect against double calling;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class MySceneParams {
    public System.Action<MySceneOutcome> callback;
    // + inputs of the scene 
}

public class MySceneOutcome {
    // + outputs of the scene 
}
```

You can keep global state in the *caller*'s scope, so scene inputs and outputs states can be minimized (makes testing easy). To use it you can use anonymous functions:-

```
MyBigGameServices services ...
MyBigGameState bigState ...

Splash.loadScene(bigState.player.name, () => {
   FirstLevel.loadScene(bigState.player, (firstLevelResult) => {
       // do something else
       services.savePlayer(firstLevelResult);
   })
)}
```

More info at https://corepox.net/devlog/unity-pattern:-stateless-scenes

Comment: I love it, but you should add an example of a life cycle of this logic, it took me time to understand how to implement it in practice

Answer (score 4):

There are various way, but assuming that you have to pass just some basic data, you can create a singelton instance of a GameController and use that class to store the data.

and, of course DontDestroyOnLoad is mandatory!

```
public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Static reference
public static GameControl control;

//Data to persist
public float health;
public float experience;

void Awake()
{
    //Let the gameobject persist over the scenes
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    //Check if the control instance is null
    if (control == null)
    {
        //This instance becomes the single instance available
        control = this;
    }
    //Otherwise check if the control instance is not this one
    else if (control != this)
    {
        //In case there is a different instance destroy this one.
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Here is the [full tutorial](https://gamedevelopertips.com/how-to-handle-data-between-scenes-in-unity/) with some other example.

Comment: Site from your link got caught by my anti-virus as infected, next it showed 404

Answer (score 2):

you have several options.

The first one I see is to use static variables, which you will not lose their information or value passing from scenes to scenes (since they are not bound to the object). [you lose the information when closing the game, but not when passing between scenes]

the second option is that the player or the object of which you do not want to lose the information, you pass it through the DontDestroyOnLoad function
Here I give you the documentation and the sample code. [You lose the information when you close the game, but not when you go between scenes]

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Third is to use the playerPrefab [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html]
that allow you to save information and retrieve it at any time without hanging it even after closing the game [you must be very careful with the latter if you plan to use it to save data even after closing the game since you can lose the data if you close the game suddenly , since player prefab creates a file and retrieves the information from there, but it saves the file at the end or closes the app correctly]

Comment: I don't know about these somehow complicated answers above, this one is really simple and do the job perfectly, "static fields" that's all I needed