# How do I carry over data between scenes in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For a game I am developing I have a part when if the user gets too close to an enemy it switches scene to a battle scene. However I have no clue how to load that enemy into the battle screen (given that a user can battle many different enemies). Below is my current cod for the enemy. I was wondering if I could carry over it's name into the next scene or something. I just want my enemy to go from one screen to another when the scene is changed. Code would be appreciated thankyou

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FolllowAndLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform target;
public Animator anim;
public Rigidbody2D myRigidBody;
public string levelToLoad;
private static string keyname; // value I want to carry over
public float MoveSpeed;
private bool checkTrigger;
public Rigidbody2D targetRigidBody;



void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();//getting the position of our player

    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    myRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); //getting my components

    targetRigidBody = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

void Update()
{
    float distance = Vector2.Distance(target.position, myRigidBody.transform.position); //getting the distance between our player and our enemy
    if (distance < 5)
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); //moving our enemy towards our player
        anim.SetBool("checkTrigger", true);
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX", moveXvalue()); //updating the animations for our enemy
        anim.SetFloat("MoveY", moveYvalue());

    }
    else if (distance > 5)  //if out of range stop walking
    {
        anim.SetBool("checkTrigger", false);

    }
}

int moveXvalue()
{
    int value;

    if (myRigidBody.transform.position.x < target.transform.position.x && Mathf.Abs(target.position.y - myRigidBody.position.y) < Mathf.Abs(target.position.x - myRigidBody.position.x)) //these are saying if the enemy is closer in x than in y use x animations and vice versa
        value = 1;
    else if (myRigidBody.transform.position.x > target.transform.position.x && Mathf.Abs(target.position.y - myRigidBody.position.y) < Mathf.Abs(target.position.x - myRigidBody.position.x))
        value = -1;
    else
        value = 0;
    return value;
}

int moveYvalue()
{
    int value;

    if (myRigidBody.transform.position.y < target.transform.position.y && Mathf.Abs(target.position.y - myRigidBody.position.y) > Mathf.Abs(target.position.x - myRigidBody.position.x))
        value = 1;
    else if (myRigidBody.transform.position.x > target.transform.position.x && Mathf.Abs(target.position.y - myRigidBody.position.y) > Mathf.Abs(target.position.x - myRigidBody.position.x))
        value = -1;
    else
        value = 0;
    return value;
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name);

        anim.SetBool("checkInContact", true);

        Application.LoadLevel (levelToLoad); //loading our level


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity - pass data between scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306704/unity-pass-data-between-scenes). Finding this duplicate required no work. It was the first suggested question when I hit close as duplicate.

Comment: @Draco18s not a duplicate as he wanted to load text (a score value) and me a character

Comment: Same principle applies to both, please keep in mind we are not a code writing service, answers should not be cut and pasteable. You can use the same methods listed to move a score as you can a player object, please try some of the suggested answers first.

Comment: P.s. answer 2 should be of use to you in the linked question, best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but the simplest way to get something working quickly just until you get more familiar with Unity it to use a simple static class in your project that you can access from any script in any scene.

So if you were to make a new script in your project right now called SharedResources.cs and then pasted this into the script and saved it....

```
public static class SharedResources
{
    public const int kSceneIs_TitleScene = 0;
    public const int kSceneIs_ActualGameScene = 1;
    public const int kSceneIs_HighScoreScene = 2;

    public static int highScore = 0;
    public static int enemyID = 0;

    public static void sampleFunction()
    {
        //this is a sample method you can call from any other script
    }

}
```

You could now be in a script in one scene and do this

```
SharedResources.highScore=SharedResources.highScore+20;
SharedResources.enemyID=5;
```

You could then open up a new scene and a script in that scene could access the high score

```
Debug.Log(SharedResources.highScore)
Debug.Log(SharedResources.enemyID)
```

You can also access constant and run subroutines that are in the static class as shown above.

The correct way to do this is up for debate and really depends on what your ultimate goal is. I will reference another link to a post that goes into more detail....

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110958/unity-5-what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-data-between-scenes

Ideally, you should read and understand the difference between using a simple static class versus one that derives from MonoBehavior, and also the different between a static class and a Singleton, which in many ways is much more powerful (but can also cause issues if you don't code it correctly)

Last but not least, don't forget you can also use the built in PlayerPrefs function in Unity to store scores and other settings that need to carry over between launches of the game....

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1325056/how-to-use-playerprefs-2.html