# how can i retain my player score to a new scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple script to count up a score for the player, how can I take this value and display it on a game over scene?

This is my score script:

```
public class scoreScript : MonoBehaviour {

 public static int scoreValue = 0;
 Text score;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     score = GetComponent<Text>();
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     score.text = "Score:" + scoreValue;
 }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity - pass data between scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306704/unity-pass-data-between-scenes)

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just call “scoreScript.scoreValue” in any script you want in game over scene

Comment: could i get an example of how to call it sorry

Answer (score 1):

Store it in `PlayerPrefs` while you exit current scene save it in playerpref like :

```
PlayerPrefs.Setint(" CurrentScore",scoreValue);
```

then retrive it in new scene by :

```
scoreValue = PlayerPrefs.Getint(" CurrentScore");
```

Comment: i tried this but i dont think it worked, i cant find where i would attach it to my score text

Comment: If you look closely, none of the other answers actually answer the question but this one does !

Answer (score 0):

You already made it `public static`, all that's left is to write in your game over scene's text field script:

```
gameOverText.text = "Score: " + scoreScript.scoreValue;
```

assuming that `gameOverText` is a `Text`.

You don't need to create an instance to access a static member, you should access them using a class name (`scoreScript` in your case).

However, it's not good to mix storing global score and a textField for displaying it in a single class, because as you add new features to the game, all global variables will be in different classes, and you will pay increasingly more attention while modifying your code. To avoid this, you may use a static class as a "core" where you store all global variables. For the first time, this will do.

`DontDestroyOnLoad` works with `GameObject`s, so they will not destroyed when a new Scene is loaded. If you call it in your script, your score counting GameObject will remain, and so will a text field because it's a compoment of that object, and will be present on game over scene, so don't do it.

Comment: i think i added it to the code correctly and it compiled with no errors but it doesnt seem to do anything any tips?

Comment: Your script for game over label should be enabled and be on an enabled GameObject. You may add `Debug.Log("...");` in it to see if the function was called.

Comment: im getting an error saying i havent called the script score variable, how do i actually instantiate it?

Answer (score -2):

When you are loading a new scene, the gameObject that carries the "scoreScript" is lost. In order to transfer the same gameobject to a new scene (which makes sense in order to not lose your information that the script is carrying), you need to use the "DontDestroyOnLoad" method.
You just call the method in the Awake method of your monobehaviour, and then your gameobject (together with the data on your script) will persist new scene loading.
Here is the relevant documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

and here is a code sample:

```
public class scoreScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int scoreValue = 0;
    Text score;

    void Awake(){
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }

    void Start () {
        score = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Update () {
        score.text = "Score:" + scoreValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, using a static value for score keeping makes global access easy, but you may want to consider the use of events for updating your score value (i.e. when something happens an event is raised and the score manager responds to that event by increasing the score)
This way you will also not need to always repeat the "score.text = "Score:" + scoreValue;" in the Update method