# How to change skin Character in Unity, and take the character in another Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

My game has a scene that has the option to select the character, but when I go to the other scene I can't get references from the previous scene, so how do I know which character was chosen from the previous scene and put to appear in the new one?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity - pass data between scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306704/unity-pass-data-between-scenes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

Unity provides a cool thing called PlayerPrefs, and it also saves on your local disk when you leave. Here's an example of a game I made using PlayerPrefs: infinitecarspeeder.netlify.com. I would make a method when you hit the button, it sets a PlayerPref named skin:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("ChosenSkin", "Josh");
```

If you do not want your player's skin to save when you leave:

```
PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("ChosenSkin");
```

For more info, see this link:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Hope it helps!