# How do I Pass a string variable Through Different Scenes? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Have 2 scripts. In one, you have a function where you can sign in. It needs a username and I want that username on a TMP Text that is located on the main menu scene.

```
    public string Username;
```

It IS a public string. Other script:

```
    public TextMeshProUGUI playerName;
```

And that is the TMP Text on which the player's username should be displayed.

I know how I could pass variables between scripts, but I don't know how to pass them through whole scenes.

Kinda rushed sorry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data between scenes in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306704/how-to-pass-data-between-scenes-in-unity)

Comment: DontDestroyOnLoad only works for root GO's or components on root GO's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

Set players name on PlayerPrefs after login:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Name", m_PlayerName);
```

Later load it on another scene from PlayerPrefs:

```
m_PlayerName = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Name", "No Name");
```

Comment: It works except... I need to reset it when I stop the program. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a static value. Static values preserve between scenes.

Comment: Hello @GraniteSOS, to delete the key later, just use this: PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Name");

Answer (score 0):

And if you would like to keep it persist between scenes PlayerPrefs would work as well.