# How to hide an object in another unity scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Let's say I have scene A and Scene B and there is one object in each scene. There is also a script attached to the Object in scene A and I wanna hide the object in scene B trough that script.

If I'd do "public GameObject ObjectB;" I couldn't drag ObjectB in cuz it's in another scene.

Also tags don't affect other scenes.

Hope u can help.
Also sorry if the solution is obvious, Im new to unity

Comment: I would refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60408573/7111561) .. of course there are multiple possible solutions as well in the others .. in particular `static`s might be a quick and simple one ;)

Answer (score 0):

To transfer data between scenes, use [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html). Create a variable that is responsible for activating this object in all scenes and check it when loading the scene

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Data", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/SpawnManagerScriptableObject", order = 1)]
public class SpawnManagerScriptableObject : ScriptableObject
{
    public bool isObjectEnabled;
}
```