# Unity save scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is what I have:
[image]

All my information about player , guns are stored in monobehaviour scripts which are placed on them.When I press that button , scene2 gets activated.However , what should I do to "teleport" my player in the next scene?I would also like to get there my UI(healthbar , bullets).I've watched some videos about singletons but I'm not sure if that's my case.Any advice?

Comment: .. either use [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) or use [additive scene loading](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html) ... also see [How to pass data between Scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306704/how-to-pass-data-between-scenes-in-unity)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DontDestroyOnLoad()`. This does what it says. Basically, it doesn’t destroy your game object when you load the new scene. You should remove the player prefab from the **other** scene, and put this in your player script:

```cs
...
   void Awake()
   {
       DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
       ...
   }
...
```

This way, if all of your variables are stored on this script, they will save because they are not being destroyed through scenes.

This will save game objects childed to this. If it doesn’t, make other variables for the children. Then, add multiple *DontDestroyOnLoad();* statements with the different variables in the different statements.

(Note: this will not save it if you stop the game or close the application. It will keep the values through scenes, not game ends or app closes.)