# Unity Timer Reset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I have a timer in my game which should count the time till the end of the game. I can't figure out how to make it so it will only reset back to 0 when menu scene is active (build index 0).' The second problem is that I don't want it to go back to 0 after every death(scene reload). Have you got any sugestions?

```
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour { 
public Text TimerText; 
public bool shouldCountTime; 
public float t;

 private void Start()
 {
     if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex != 0)
     {
         shouldCountTime = true;
     }
     else
     {
         shouldCountTime = false;
         t = 0;
     }
     t = Time.deltaTime;
 }
 void Update()
 {
     if (shouldCountTime) {
         t += Time.deltaTime;
     }
     string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
     string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");
     TimerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
 } 
}
```

Comment: you can use the [sceneLoaded](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html) event to check what scene is loaded and set your timer according to your need. Also check [dontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) to make elements persistent between scenes.

Comment: Maybe you should checkout [How to pass data between scenes in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306704/how-to-pass-data-between-scenes-in-unity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you should make it a singleton (meaning only one instance should exist at a time - **not** speaking about the general (ab)use of having a public static reference ;) )

And use [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) in order to keep your object also when the scene is changed and for the resetting use [`SceneManager.sceneLoaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html) and check the index of the newly loaded scene like e.g.

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    // Make sure this text is also not destroyed
    // e.g. make its entire canvas a child of this object
    public Text TimerText; 
    public bool shouldCountTime; 
    public float t;

    // Singleton Pattern -> make sure only one instance exists in your scene
    private static Timer _instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // does another instance already exist?
        if(_instance && _instance != this)
        {
            // if so detroy this one
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        // This is the active instance
        _instance = this;

        // Don't destroy this GameObject when a new scene is loaded
        DontDestroyOnload(gameObject);

        // Attach a callback for every new scene that is loaded
        // It is fine to remove a callback that wasn't added so far
        // This makes sure that this callback is definitely only added once
        // usually I do this only as a kind of convention
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    // Will be called every time a scene is loaded
    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        // check the build index
        shouldCountTime = scene.buildIndex != 0;

        // Reset in the main menu
        if(!shouldCountTime)
        {
            Debug.Log("Reset timer", this);
            t = 0;
            TimerText.text = "0:00";
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // Even though your object most probably lives during the entire application lifetime
        // again just as a convention always remove callbacks as soon as not needed anymore
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }

     void Update()
     {
         // do your calculations only while the value is actually changing
         if (!shouldCountTime) return;

         t += Time.deltaTime;
         var minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
         var seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");
         TimerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
     } 
}
```

---

If changing the hierarchy (regarding e.g. the Text) is not an option than rather refer to [How to pass data between scenes in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306704/how-to-pass-data-between-scenes-in-unity) for alternative solutions for caring over the value.

Comment: Should the timer be an invidually gameobject?

Comment: @AndreiPreda if you don't want other stuff to be affected by `DontDestroyOnLoad` then yes!

Comment: I  just came home, tested it but when the next scene is loading it says : "The object of type 'Text' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.'

Comment: Yes of course .. se my first comment in the code ^^