# How can my ScriptableObjects have a SerializeField reference to a Script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, logic, scriptable-object

Each enemy in my game is a Scriptable Object (Enemy1, Enemy2, etc). Each enemy also has its own unique script to determine how battles go (BattleEvent1, BattleEvent2, etc)

The way my logic currently works is:

1. `BattleSystem` component has all `BattleEvent`s attached to it.
2. When battle starts, check the `name` of the current `Enemy`, and use that string reference to pick which `BattleEvent` to run (LOTS of if statements).

But this is bad because it's all string references, so I can't easily ensure that each enemy has a `BattleEvent`, and there's a lot of if/else statements.

What I wanted to do was attach each `BattleEvent` script to its respective `Enemy` Scriptable Object.

[image]

But I'm not able to drag the scripts in that Battle Event SerializeField there.

I would ideally like my logic to work like:

1. `BattleSystem` loads the enemy, and just checks the `Enemy.BattleEvent` to load the proper script.

Since I can't attach scripts to the SOs, I can't get this to work. Is there any way I can achieve a logic flow like this?

Comment: You can't have **scene references** in assets. You can however assign the reference on runtime! See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60408573/7111561) where I describe how to use a provider and consumer pattern via ScriptableObjects

Comment: Thanks for the link. Perhaps I need to do more research on the provider/consumer pattern, but I wasn't sure how to relate your answer to the issue described above. But what I think I've realized since I posted this is, the question I really needed to ask is "Can you assign an arbitrary script as a SerializeField?". If I'm understanding your post, you are only assigning basic data types to the objects, so I think there is still my issue of not being able to associate scripts to SOs, not regular variables. That's assuming I didn't completely misunderstand your post!

Comment: You can assign to the SO whatever you want ;) also e.g. Dictionary and other non-serialized values. You won't be able to do so in edit mode but only on runtime though. Basically the same as if you would use a static class .. but with SO you are more flexible and can use multiple ones of the se types without having conflicts .. as you can see in my post I also used it to pass on a `Transform` reference as well as a complete custom class instance containing a Dictionary