# What is the best way to read changeable variable values between scenes in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to pass variable values between scenes in unity, I've tried using static variables but it gives me an error when I try to edit it.

Comment: Has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306704/how-to-pass-data-and-references-between-scenes-in-unity)

Answer (score 1):

Use `PlayerPrefs` to store values. For example, If I wanted to a variable, I would go into the script then enter:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SceneSwitch : MonoBehaviour {

//Declare variable
int var1 = 2f;

//Go into where you would move then use PlayerPrefs to store values
void SwitchScene() {
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("var", var1);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
}

//Load the values from another scene (put this into another script)
int LoadThing() {
return PlayerPrefs.GetInt("var");
}



}
```

Comment: I would not update the player prefs in any `Update` function. You can determine when a scene is loading/unloading. Setting and saving player prefs that frequently is not performant at all.

Comment: Correct, I'm just showing an example of how to use it, that's all.