# Serializing nested polymorphical objects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, polymorphism, unity3d-editor

Hi fellow game developers, I'm working on a Unity project that allows level designer to edit instructions to scene elements of how they should act to events.

[screenshot of command editor in unity inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2740Z.png)

I've managed to express all executable instruction units--expressions, statements, control blocks--with a common abstract base class `Command`. It comes like this:

```
[Serializable]
abstract class Command {
    public abstract object Execute();
    public abstract void Inspect(/* ... */);
}
class CommandCarrier : MonoBehaviour {
    public Command command;
}
/*
    There are several carrier classes in the real project,
    this one is only for illustrating the problem.
    Command.Inspect() would be called by a CustomEditor of CommandCarrier.
*/
```

Where `Execute()` is to perform the command at runtime, and `Inspect()` is to draw the inspector GUIs.

Every solid type of command would be a derived class of `Command`, e.g. an if-else block would be like:

```
[Serializable]
class Conditional : Command {
    public Command condition, trueBranch, falseBranch;
    public override object Execute() {
        if((bool)condition.Execute()) trueBranch.Execute();
        else falseBranch.Execute();
        return null;
    }
    public override void Inspect(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
}
```

A constant expression would contain no sub-commands:

```
[Serializable]
class Constant<T> : Command {
    public T value = default(T);
    public override object Execute() => value;
    public override void Inspect(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Here comes the problem: all the commands I've written in the inspector panel would be lost as long as a reserialization is triggered (like when the code changed and therefore is recompiled).
This is probably because Unity failed to serialize a subclass instance stored in a field of base class; all the type information and the contained data are lost during reserialization.
What's worse is that these polymorphical instances are even nested.

I've tried to solve the case and failed: given a field of base class, it's apparently impossible to "upgrade" an instance to a subclass by calling whatever methods belonging to that instance; it must be done externally by assigning the field with a subclass instance created elsewhere.
But again, every subclasses have their own fields, and these data I haven't figure out where to recover from.

Could anybody help?

Comment: Since your `Command` is a `MonoBehaviour` the (de)serialization actually only has to do with a **reference** (GUID) which should be totally fine. I suspect rather something in your Inspector implementation / within your `Inspect` is wrong .. in specific not marking setting the fields **dirty** correctly after changes! Could you show us some example Inspector implementations?

Comment: @derHugo Oh sorry! I got the place of `MonoBehaviour` wrong when I transcribed my code in to problem description; there is another class that derives from `MonoBehaviour` instead of `Command`. I'll be fixing my description!

Comment: @derHugo `Inspect()` is simply bunch of calls to `GUILayout`/`EditorGUILayout` methods. They are called in `OnInspectorGUI()` of a editor class derived from CustomEditor. About marking fields dirty, instead of manipulating `SerializedObject` I modify the fields directly when inspector value changes. Is that somehow a wrong way to implement?

Comment: yes that can definitely lead to issues ... you should never mix Editor scripting with direct access and assignments of the fields but rather go through `SerializedObject` and `SerializedProperty` ... otherwise you will definitely get issues with the dirt state, undo/redo and changes not being saved (due to the lack of dirty marking)

Comment: Have you tried using [[SerializeReference\]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeReference.html) to serialize the polymorphic stuff?

Comment: @Ruzihm I haven't heard of this attribute, thanks for letting me know. This helps in another problem where I need to keep track of circular reference. (God I hate that C# doesn't support pointers to objects)

Comment: New problem: I can't find an appropriate timing to finalize the ScriptableObject assets when removing/resetting the script component, thus leaving them unmanaged & hanging in the asset folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you corrected your code here I would point you to [Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) and in particular the section

> **No support for polymorphism**
>
> If you have a `public Animal[] animals` and you put in an instance of a `Dog`, a `Cat` and a `Giraffe`, after serialization, you have three instances of `Animal`.
>
> One way to deal with this limitation is to realize that it only applies to custom classes, which get serialized inline. References to other `UnityEngine.Objects` get serialized as actual references, and for those, polymorphism does actually work. You would make a `ScriptableObject` derived class or another `MonoBehaviour` derived class, and reference that. The downside of this is that you need to store that `Monobehaviour` or scriptable object somewhere, and that you cannot serialize it inline efficiently.
>
> The reason for these limitations is that one of the core foundations of the serialization system is that the layout of the datastream for an object is known ahead of time; it depends on the types of the fields of the class, rather than what happens to be stored inside the fields.

So in your case I would simply use `ScriptableObject` and do

```
abstract class Command : ScriptableObject
{
    public abstract object Execute();
    public abstract void Inspect(/* ... */);
}
```

and

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Conditional : Command 
{
    public Command condition, trueBranch, falseBranch;
    public override object Execute() {
        if((bool)condition.Execute()) trueBranch.Execute();
        else falseBranch.Execute();
        return null;
    }
    public override void Inspect(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
}
```

and

```
public abstract class Constant<T> : Command 
{
    public T value = default(T);
    public override object Execute() => value;
    public override void Inspect(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
}
```

and e.g.

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class IntConstant : Constant<int>
{
}
```

each in their own script files with matching name (that part is very important for the serializer).

And then you would create instance of these via the Assets -> right click -> Create -> "Conditional" for example and reference it into the according slots.

Also note that these are now re-usable and you can simply reference the same item in various places, something that wasn't possible if you use a normal serializable class due to

> **When might the serializer behave unexpectedly?**
>
> **Custom classes behave like structs**
>
> With custom classes that are not derived from UnityEngine.Object Unity serializes them inline by value, similar to the way it serializes structs. If you store a reference to an instance of a custom class in several different fields, they become separate objects when serialized. Then, when Unity deserializes the fields, they contain different distinct objects with identical data.
>
> When you need to serialize a complex object graph with references, do not let Unity automatically serialize the objects. Instead, use `ISerializationCallbackReceiver` to serialize them manually. This prevents Unity from creating multiple objects from object references. For more information, see documentation on `ISerializationCallbackReceiver`.
>
> This is only true for custom classes. Unity serializes custom classes “inline” because their data becomes part of the complete serialization data for the `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject` they are used in. When fields reference something that is a `UnityEngine.Object`-derived class, such as `public Camera myCamera`, Unity serializes an actual reference to the camera `UnityEngine.Object`. The same occurs in instances of scripts if they are derived from `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject`, which are both derived from `UnityEngine.Object`.

Comment: Thank you sir, I tried your method and it worked. But there is one fatal problem: since I'm adding references to one same asset created from each subclasses of `Command`, I can't actually have different versions of a type of command. Do I need to create an asset every time I want to use a type of command? If so, how do I manage to create such abundant amount of assets without messing up my asset folder?

Comment: @NianyiWang yes everytime a new asset except it shall really be the same ;) And use subfolders ;)

Comment: Careful, that documentation is a bit out of date. As [this more recent version](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.1/Documentation/Manual/script-Serialization.html) shows, it is currently possible to serialize polymorphic stuff using [[SerializeReference\]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeReference.html). I don't know if it can be used in this *particular* use case, but it's no longer *generally* true that serialization does not support polymorphism.

Comment: @Ruzihm the doc I refer to is not out of date but the current latest LTS version though. Yours is of 2022 which is still in Beta and not production ready! In general `SerializeReference` is worth a shot .. never understood its purpose / got it working so far ^^

Comment: Good point, here is a non-beta version of the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/script-Serialization.html.

Comment: @Ruzihm that's 2021 which also is not yet LTS but a Tech Stream release which provides early access to the newest features etc but is not LTS supported for production neither ;)

Comment: Update: I now need to refer to scene objects in commands (e.g. I may want to make certain character move via command), and sadly that is impossible using scriptable objects :-(

Comment: @NianyiWang it's not completely impossible ;) see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60408573/7111561)

Comment: @derHugo Man, I don't think that's a valid solution... You see, when editing in the inspector, there are gonna be nested commands stored in one game object. If I'm storing command data in monobehaviours, I'm basically putting more than one monobehaviours into one game object, which is somehow illegal, I guess?