# Parameter 'isWalking" does not exist. UnityEngine.Animator:SetBool (string, bool) how to fix

Tags: c#

i dont know how to fix this error, i wanted to move a character in a unity 3D game but it gives me this error, i cant find any solutions on the internet and im not experienced so i dont know what to do, this is writed in C#

"Parameter 'isWalking' does not exist. UnityEngine.Animator:SetBool (string, bool)"

here is the code that i wanted to use:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{



    public abstract class Command
    {
        public abstract void Execute();
    }

    public class JumpFunction : Command
    {
        public override void Execute()
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }

    public class TelekinesisFunction : Command
    {
        public override void Execute()
        {
            Telekinesis();
        }
    }


    public static void Telekinesis()
    {

    }

    public static void Jump()
    {

    }

    public static void DoMove()
    {
        Command keySpace = new JumpFunction();
        Command keyX = new TelekinesisFunction();

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            keySpace.Execute();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
        {
            keyX.Execute();
        }
    }


    public CharacterController characterController;
    public float speed = 3;


    public Animator animator;

    // camera and rotation
    public Transform cameraHolder;
    public float mouseSensitivity = 2f;
    public float upLimit = -50;
    public float downLimit = 50;

    // gravity
    private float gravity = 9.87f;
    private float verticalSpeed = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        Move();
        Rotate();
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    public void Rotate()
    {
        float horizontalRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float verticalRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        transform.Rotate(0, horizontalRotation * mouseSensitivity, 0);
        cameraHolder.Rotate(-verticalRotation * mouseSensitivity, 0, 0);

        Vector3 currentRotation = cameraHolder.localEulerAngles;
        if (currentRotation.x > 180) currentRotation.x -= 360;
        currentRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.x, upLimit, downLimit);
        cameraHolder.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        float horizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (characterController.isGrounded) verticalSpeed = 0;
        else verticalSpeed -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 gravityMove = new Vector3(0, verticalSpeed, 0);

        Vector3 move = transform.forward * verticalMove + transform.right * horizontalMove;
        characterController.Move(speed * Time.deltaTime * move + gravityMove * Time.deltaTime);

        animator.SetBool("isWalking", verticalMove != 0 || horizontalMove != 0);




    }
}
```

Comment: What you appear to be doing is trying to set a property on a `GameObject` via an `AnimatorController`.  Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32306704/102937)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear.

> "Parameter 'isWalking' does not exist. UnityEngine.Animator:SetBool
> (string, bool)"

So there is no [animation parameter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) named `isWalking`. Either you have a typo in the parameter name or you did not create it.

Only you know why you think you can set this particular parameter.

Please read this in case you haven't:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationSection.html