# How to make Transition scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my character enters the door which takes them to stage 2 but when the character goes back to the portal which goes back to stage 1 they go back to where the game started and not in front of the door

I tried to make my character move from the second scene to the first, but to the place where she entered the second scene

Comment: Then you need to remember where she was

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow, and presumably, programming.

What you are looking for, is a way to 'transfer' data between scenes as they switch. Though there is no direct way to transfer data between scene, your desired effect can be done by

1. Having a globally accessible  **Singleton** or **Static** instance.
2. When a scene loads, a script will read data from the instance *(in your case, it will read to determine the player's starting position)*

---

#### Static Types

In your case, I recommend using **static** types, you can look into [this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp/) or [this short video](https://youtu.be/8xcIy9cV-6g).

```
public static class GlobalData {
    // Use an Enum if you need to represent more states,
    // or you can setup a more sophisticated state machine if necessary.
    public static bool PlayerCameFromStage2 { get; set; }
}
```

```
// In your player script...
public class YourPlayerScript: MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        // Access the global static data here...
        if (GlobalData.PlayerCameFromStage2) {
            // Move to other starting point...
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you would like to look into singleton, I recommend checking out [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPKAgyp8cno), and then looking into [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html).

> As Singleton relies on having a GameObject "store" your data, which will be destroyed whenever you switch scenes by default.
> The `DontDestroyOnLoad` ensures that the GameObject doesn't get destroyed whenever scenes are switched.

---

*P.S. The programming Jargon you are looking for `data persistence`, as you would like some data to persist when changing between scenes. Which you can use said data to check where the player needs to spawn at.*

Comment: Good answer. However, consider a simpler solution first: iin this case it would probably be enough to just manually place the Player object at the location where they should start in the second scene.

Comment: @KamielDev OP wanted to allow the player to backtrack from stage2 into stage1, the difference is requiring the player to be spawned in a different spot. Copy-pasting a new Stage1 and editing the player is a valid solution, but its inflexible and not a good practice for OP to learn *(If OP decides to do edits on stage1, edits have to be done twice, etc)*; In this case, using static is the simplest solution, OP just has to set a static variable, read from it on stage load, and a simple if-else statement to set player's position for stage1. Plus, introduces OP on how to use static instances

Comment: you are totally right, I must have misunderstood the question.

Comment: There is quite a couple of more solutions ;) See linked duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306704/how-to-pass-data-and-references-between-scenes-in-unity