# Why can't I reference UI elements in Unity? (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made a scriptable object that holds all the UI references needed in the game so it can be easily accessed in any script:

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "UIDataReferences", menuName = "UIDataReferences", order = 1)]
public class UIDataReferences : ScriptableObject
{
    [Header("Health UI")]
    public Slider bossHealthSlider;
    public Slider bossHealthLagSlider;
    public TMP_Text bossName;
}
```

However in the Unity editor it won't let me drag and drop any of the three elements into their respective fields. If I add the following line:

```
public _NPC npcData;
```

to the above script, I can reference that Scriptable Object fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a `ScriptableObject` which is an **asset**. It is not "allowed" to store references to objects in the Scene in assets. Which makes sense since as soon as you unload the scene (aka e.g. close Unity) the objects are unloaded and don't exist anymore -> the references are gone (!Missing!)

Comment: `I've made a scriptable object that holds all the UI references needed in the game so it can be easily accessed in any script` that is quite bad/lazy practice .. but you can do so by initializing them on runtime - see e.g. my answer to [How to pass data (and references) between scenes in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306704/how-to-pass-data-and-references-between-scenes-in-unity/60408573#60408573) -> you could simply have a writer component on your UI with the sole purpose of setting those references in `Awake`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference instances of objects in a scene from a `ScriptableObject` asset. Maybe during runtime but that's it.

I also don't think this is the best case for a `ScriptableObject`. They are not designed as a shortcut to keep references between scripts. It's mainly useful for creating multiple instances of the same thing (like inventory items) while being serialized as an asset, and its ability to reference other serialized assets. I can't see why you would have more than one `UIDataReference` that utilized the same fields.

Just use another `MonoBehaviour` for this. In fact it sounds like you want a `Singleton` which you can easily reference from anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have them attached to a gameobject? Also do you have the sliders attached to gameobjects and are you dragging that gameobject into it? You should be able to drag the item into them with what you have here. You could try: Assets -> Reimport All and it might help.

Another way to reference them is in the start method do something like this:

```
bossHealthSlider = GameObject.Find("BossGameObjectName").GetComponent<Slider>();
```