Solution to 'Type Mismatch' error stopping me from assigning a GameObject to a prefab in Unity
Whenever I try to assign a GameObject or TMP Text Box to a prefab's public variable, I get an error message that says, "Type Mismatch". The variable is a list (used to be array) and I am not sure if it has something to do with prefab or public lists or arrays.
Here's the two scripts I have:
"OreMiner"
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;

public class OreMiner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float miningRate = 1.0f; // Ores per second
    public List<string> oreTags; // List of tags for different ore types
    public List<TMP_Text> oreCountTexts; // List of UI texts to update ore count for each type
    private Dictionary<string, int> totalOres = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    public SetOreCountTexts SetOre; // Ensure this is of type SetOreCountTexts

    void Start()
    {
        // Check if SetOre is assigned
        if (SetOre != null && SetOre.textList != null)
        {
            // Initialize oreCountTexts from SetOre
            oreCountTexts = new List<TMP_Text>(SetOre.textList);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("SetOre or SetOre.textList is not assigned.");
            return;
        }

        // Initialize ore counts for each type
        foreach (string tag in oreTags)
        {
            totalOres[tag] = 0;
        }

        StartCoroutine(MineOres());
    }

    IEnumerator MineOres()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f / miningRate);
            CollectOres();
        }
    }

    void CollectOres()
    {
        foreach (string oreTag in oreTags)
        {
            Collider[] oresInRange = Physics.OverlapBox(transform.position, transform.localScale / 2, Quaternion.identity, LayerMask.GetMask(oreTag));
            foreach (var ore in oresInRange)
            {
                totalOres[oreTag]++;
                Destroy(ore.gameObject); // Remove the ore from the scene
            }
        }
        UpdateUI();
    }



    void UpdateUI()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < oreTags.Count; i++)
        {
            string oreTag = oreTags[i];
            oreCountTexts[i].text = $"{oreTag} Collected: {totalOres[oreTag]}";
        }
    }
}

"SetOreCountTexts"
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class SetOreCountTexts : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<TMP_Text> textList = new List<TMP_Text>();
}

I had "SetOreCountTexts" assigned to an empty Game Object in the scene with the list of Text Boxes and tried to force the TextBoxes into the prefab but that didn't work.
I looked around on other posts with similar problems to mine, but the problem did not fix, like this one Unity Type Mismatch For Prefabs and other duplicates of my problem. I tried changing the code a little bit but to no avail. I also tried creating a scripted object and assigning the text boxes to the scripted object. I also tried unpacking the prefab, inputting the text boxes into the resultant object, and re-make the prefab but whenever I re-created the prefab the list of text boxes just cleared. Is there any fix or workaround to this problem?

Are you trying to put texts from the scene into a prefab asset?  That for obvious reasons would not work..  Do you get an error in the console that says type mismatch?  Are you sure you are using the correct type?  You mention TextBox, but are using Text for list..  Please be specific

I know it doesn't work otherwise I wouldn't be asking the question...I am only looking for a workaround to the issue (maybe a solution). The console did not output an error message that says, "Type Mismatch", its whenever I try to put the TMP text boxes into the list is when the little dropdown menu for the element says type mismatch. And yes, I am 110% sure I am using the correct type.

TMP_Text is not a textbox, it would more commonly be referred to as a label or text component.  Im thinking you mean a TMP_InputField

In general you can't have references to scene objects in assets like prefabs ... And the duplicates you mention pretty much explain exactly that .... What exactly are you trying to achieve by that and why do you think you need a workaround? You can do this on runtime - but it will not be persistent .. see e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60408573/7111561

Otherwise you would have to go for Odin Inspector which supports that .. though no idea how they implemented it and how efficient it really is .. https://www.odininspector.com

If you are using Text mesh pro component for your UI text then you need to create this type of reference TextMeshProUGUI
That means instead of having this
public List<TMP_Text> oreCountTexts;

You should change it to this
public List<TextMeshProUGUI> oreCountTexts;

You can read more about it here: TextMesh Pro Documentation

That's not true as TMP_Text is the parent type and works as well.. same as Collider and Renderer would simply accept any child type reference

Yes, indeed TMP_Text is a more generic class but is often used for non-UI objects in the world environment instead of the canvas. That's why I said in my answer, If you are using it for UI Text, because TextMeshProUGUI is designed specifically for UI elements.

I know .. you can limit it down to the specific type if you desire .. but it doesn't matter .. and this doesn't solve the question here.. you said you need to ... .. and that's not true. You don't have to and in general being open for more general types is usually better
